# Finally block to execute when all async calls completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, try-catch-finally

I am looking to get a hold of this situation where i have a parent method - EventMethod, which internally calls another method - Handler1().
Handler1() internally calls async methods which internally calls some other async methods. The chain continues a little long.

How can I execute my finally statement only when all the async calls are compeleted ?
In the code below, the finally is immediately called once the await is hit inside the calling Handler1() method

```
void EventMethod()
{
try { 
 Helper.Handler1();
 } catch(Exception ex){}
finally{
  GlobalVariable.ExecutionCompleted = true;
}
```

Comment: `Handler1();` what is the return type of this method

Answer (score 3):

```
async void EventMethod()
{
  try 
  { 
    await Helper.Handler1(); //Make sure this return Task
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }
  finally
  {
    GlobalVariable.ExecutionCompleted = true;
  }
}
```

**Mocking your Helper**

```
    private static Task Handler1()
    {
        var t1 = DoSomething2();
        var t2 = DoSomething3();
        return Task.WhenAll(t1, t2); //You could return the task or await here itself 
    }

    private static Task DoSomething2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethign 2");
        return Task.Delay(3000);
    }

    private static Task DoSomething3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethign 3");
        return Task.Delay(3000);
    }
```

You can get working example [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cz6rFS). I have tried to reproduce my understanding of your question. In example you could find Two task that can be executed parallely

Answer (score -1):

Your handler method is returning as `Task`. You can call `Wait()` on it. See [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: If you call `Wait()` then it sort of defeats the purpose of `async`

Comment: But it does not look like a normal `EventHandler` (it is missing `EventArgs`), so I suspected it to be a kind of callback. If it is a normal `EventHandler` you could use `async void` as Eldho suggested. Which is the only normal recommended usage of `async void`.

Comment: Yes that's true.  I wasn't down-voter by the way. :)